# Add2BasketByProductID при количестве 0 не добавлять

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет, помогите решить вопрос.
Есть обработчик добавления товаров в корзину:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["product_id"]) && CModule::IncludeModule("sale") && CModule::IncludeModule("catalog")){
            foreach($_REQUEST['product_id'] as $PRODUCT_ID){
                $quantity = 0;  
                if((int)$_REQUEST['quantity_'.(int)$PRODUCT_ID] > 0)
                     $quantity = (int)$_REQUEST['quantity_'.(int)$PRODUCT_ID];
                Add2BasketByProductID( (int)$PRODUCT_ID, $quantity);
            }
            LocalRedirect($APPLICATION->GetCurPage());
        }
```

если я передаю количество 0, то в корзину падает товар в количестве 1. Все логично, в документации битрикса написано, что стандартно товар падает в количестве 1шт. Чем нужно дополнить обработчик, чтобы при передаваемом количество 0 товар не падал в корзину?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос, маленько не так:

```
<?if(isset($_REQUEST["product_id"]) && CModule::IncludeModule("sale") && CModule::IncludeModule("catalog"))
            {
                foreach($_REQUEST['product_id'] as $PRODUCT_ID)
                {
                    $quantity = 0;  
                    if((int)$_REQUEST['quantity_'.(int)$PRODUCT_ID] > 0)
                    $quantity = (int)$_REQUEST['quantity_'.(int)$PRODUCT_ID];
                    if($quantity>0) Add2BasketByProductID((int)$PRODUCT_ID, $quantity); 
                    else 
                    {                
                    } 
                }

            }
?>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно модифицировать код следующим образом (внести Add2BasketByProductID внутрь if):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["product_id"]) && CModule::IncludeModule("sale") && CModule::IncludeModule("catalog")){
    foreach($_REQUEST['product_id'] as $PRODUCT_ID){
        $quantity = 0;  
        if((int)$_REQUEST['quantity_'.(int)$PRODUCT_ID] > 0) {
            $quantity = (int)$_REQUEST['quantity_'.(int)$PRODUCT_ID];
            Add2BasketByProductID( (int)$PRODUCT_ID, $quantity);
        }
    }
    LocalRedirect($APPLICATION->GetCurPage());
}
```